# How to exit from the Ubuntu installer after the installation is finished?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I used an Ubuntu live USB to install Ubuntu. When the installation was finished I clicked on the X button and did a power off. Then a message told me to remove the USB Ubuntu installation media and press Enter, so I did that. Now I don't know what to do next because the PC is still running, but there is a only a blank black screen showing.

Comment: You've not given any specifics as to what Ubuntu product & release you're talking about.  There is a bug for example with ISOs of Xubuntu using `ubiquity` that prevents the *eject media and press enter to reboot* for example (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1944519) but you've not said which you're using, if it's a `subiquity`, `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, `ubiquity` or `calamares` installer/ISO you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You finished installing Ubuntu and removed the USB stick. Press the computer's power button, and hold it down until the computer shuts down. Then start the computer and it should be able to boot to Ubuntu. If you installed Ubuntu as a dual boot alongside Windows, it should boot to the GRUB boot menu which gives you a choice of booting to either Windows or Ubuntu. Otherwise if you installed Ubuntu as a single boot it will boot straight into Ubuntu.